# PHP unique numbers and replace?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

We all know the rand(x,y) in PHP, but that would not work with unique numbers.

**Question 1:**  how i can create 5 unique numbers from 1-52, and save them to an array?

lets say the array are:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

and i have a secound array with a few of those numbers in $foo:

```
$egg = array(1,5,4);
```

**Question 2:** how can i then make a function that would take and replace every number in the `$foo` with new unique numbers, except the numbers from `$egg`? 
( that would make `2,3` new unique numbers).

(aka: the values from `$egg` are still there in `$foo` but every other value is new)

Comment: its time to start playing around [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Comment: Do you have any spesific array functions for me to look at?

Comment: yes, `range, shuffle, array_rand, array_diff` to start with

Comment: use `array_diff()` function..

Comment: @maria FYI: The current accepted answer isn't very good: `if you need a bit of performance`. As larger as your arrays(range) get the accept answer won't work anymore! Also it has no explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 Question:**

Simply create the [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) from where you want the unique random numbers. [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and then take an [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) from it, like this:

```
<?php

    $range = range(1, 52);
    shuffle($range);
    $randomNumbers = array_slice($range, 0, 5);

    print_r($randomNumbers);

?>
```

possible output:

```
Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 32 [2] => 7 [3] => 52 [4] => 35 )
```

**2 Question:**

First get the difference from both arrays with [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). After this create  as many random numbers from the range as `$diff` has elements. But exclude all numbers which are in the `$foo` array already, so that you don't get duplicates again.

Then you can [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the numbers which you want to replace with the random numbers.

And after this simply go through all array elements with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and check if it has to be replace or not, if yes return the replaced number.

```
<?php

    $range = range(1, 52);
    $foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    $egg = [1, 5, 4];

    $diff = array_diff($foo, $egg);
    $range = array_diff($range, $foo);
    shuffle($range);

    $replacement = array_combine($diff, array_slice($range, 0, count($diff)));
    $foo = array_map(function($v)use($replacement){
        if(isset($replacement[$v]))
            return $replacement[$v];
        return $v;
    }, $foo);

    print_r($foo);

?>
```

possible output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 27 [2] => 10 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76817/discussion-between-rizier123-and-maria).

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 

// QUESTION 1
$result = array();

while(count($result) != 5) {
    $rand = rand(1,52);

    if(!in_array($rand,$result)){
        $result[] = $rand;
    } 
}
var_dump($result);


// QUESTION 2
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$egg =array(1,5,4);

function my_function($input,$exclude){


    $i = 0;
    $output = array();

    while($i < count($input)) {
        $rand = rand(1,52);

        if(in_array($input[$i], $exclude)) {
            $output[$i] = $input[$i];
            $i++;
        }

        else if(!in_array($rand, $input)){
            $output[$i] = $rand;
            $i++;
        }
    }


    return $output;
}

var_dump (my_function($foo, $egg));
```

Comment: Nice code. But, in question  two, are the $eggs values still there?

Comment: they are not modified if that's what you asked

Comment: Could you edit so the answer of question two would be that the values from $egg are still there in $foo but every other value is new?

Comment: Done, but please edit your question too because my answer dosen't match it

Comment: the question is bit confusing. my answer in question #2 is removing the the same value from foo and egg and leave the other from foo

Comment: @Med Your code for question 1 is killing performance with this loop!

Comment: @Rizier123  I implemented the first thing that came to my mind, maybe there's more performance efficient code

Comment: @Med Same for the second question, these loops are just killing performance massively. Also for the first question you have a lot of undefined variables in your answer.

Comment: this somehow upputted from the 2nd: array(27,38,27,6);

Answer (score 1):

Q#1 This would work

```
<?php
$arr = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
$rand = rand(1, 52);
if(!in_array($rand, $arr)){
    array_push($arr, $rand);
}else{
    $i--;
}
}

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Q#2

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$egg = array(1,5,4);

print_r(unique($foo, $egg));

function unique($foo, $egg){
array_merge($foo, $egg);
$unique = array_unique($foo);
return $unique;
}
```

Comment: Your code for question 1 is killing performance with this loop!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
    $r = array_rand(array_flip(range(1, 10)), 5);
    $egg = [3, 5, 8];
    $diff = array_diff(range(1, 10), $r, $egg);

    array_walk($r, function(&$item, $key) use ($egg, &$diff) {
        if (!in_array($item, $egg) && $diff) {
            $key = array_rand($diff);
            $item = $diff[$key];
            unset($diff[$key]);
        }
    });
```

1. $r - create 5 unique numbers from range
2. $diff - differece beetwen - range and $egg with $r (unique numbers, that not exists in $egg and $r)
3. array_walk - walk by $r and check, if number in $egg leave it. If number is not in $egg and not empty $diff, get random number from $diff (here unique numbers), replace current $item (number) and remove it from $diff (to avoid duplication).

Result:

```
$r = [
  0 => 1
  1 => 3
  2 => 7
  3 => 8
  4 => 10
]
$egg = [3, 5, 8];
// after walk
array:5 [
  0 => 9
  1 => 3
  2 => 2
  3 => 8
  4 => 4
]
```

This is not final version of code, but it could help you find simple and right solution.

Comment: how do i get the array containing the new numbers from the array walk?

Comment: to array_walk array passed by refernce. Item changed in function, changed in array. Function array_wlak change array passed to it.